# Why do I not have the option to vote to delete?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

[image]

Why do I not have the option to vote to delete? I'm not fussed about deleting, I can vote to close it but, as I have 20k score, I thought I should have these extra options? https://superuser.com/help/privileges/trusted-user

[image]

Comment: You don't really *need* to delete it, it'll get [roomba'ed](http://superuser.com/help/roomba) pretty soon anyway.  It's not so painfully awful that it absolutely must be gone from everyones sight *right now*, it's just bad.

Comment: I wouldn't delete it either, I'd stick with the voting to close and some one else can delete (other than spam)! That is't the point though. It's more about why it shows something which doesn't appear to be correct? @Mokubai

Comment: that's fair enough, I was just wanting to make sure you were aware that it probably would disappear one way or another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't. Or more specifically the question has not met the criteria for you to try to put it out of its misery.

> Voting to delete questions with a score of -3 or lower immediately after they are closed

The question needs one more downvote *and* to be closed.

Comment: I've updated my post... I don't *think* this is correct :S

Comment: Its a question tho

Comment: That's where I got it wrong :S Thank you